# ANGULAR and PHP : <b>Warning</b>: Undefined array key

Tags: php, angular, api, angular-httpclient

I coded an API in PHP-MySql. It works fine through PostMan.
But when I want to modify a "partenaire" via my ANGULAR application, I have this error (see image).

[image]

Any idea please?

Here's the PHP :

```
    // Update a partenaire in database
if ($api == 'PUT') {
  parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $post_input);

  $g01 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['nomfranchise']);
  $g02 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['sexegerant']);
  $g03 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['nomgerant']);
  $g04 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['mail']);
  $g05 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['password']);
  $g06 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['actif']);
  $g07 = $tuple->test_input($post_input['grants']);


  if ($id != null) {
    if ($tuple->update($g01, $g02, $g03, $g04, $g05, $g06, $g07, $id)) {
      echo $tuple->message('Partenaire modifié avec succès !',false);
    } else {
      echo $tuple->message('Erreur lors de la modification du partenaire !',true);
    }
  } else {
    echo $tuple->message('Partenaire non trouvé !',true);
  }
}
```

Then the Angular PartenaireComponent

```
  onSubmitPartenaireForm(): void{

const partenaireId = this.partenaireForm.value.id;
let partenaire = this.partenaireForm.value;
if(!partenaireId || partenaireId && partenaireId == 0){
  // CREATE ligne PARTENAIRE
  delete partenaire.id;
  this.apiService.createPartenaire(partenaire).subscribe((part: Partenaire)=>{
    console.log("Partenaire crée, ", part);
  });
} else {
  // UPDATE
  this.apiService.updatePartenaire(partenaireId, partenaire).subscribe((part: Partenaire)=>{
    console.log("Partenaire mis à jour", part);
  });
}
this.partenaireForm.reset();
this.titrePage = 'Enregistrer un nouveau partenaire';
```

}

And the ANGULAR ApiService

```
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ');
  }

  updatePartenaire(id: number, partenaire: Partenaire): Observable<Partenaire>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.httpClient.put<Partenaire>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}partenaire.php/${id}`, partenaire, { headers : headers, responseType: "json" });
  }
```

ANGULAR (front)
https://github.com/fabienmacip/sallesport.git

PHP (APIs)
https://github.com/fabienmacip/sallesport-api.git

Comment: parse_str is used to parse query string not a json. To get the posted object use json_decode and retrieve the variables. For more information see this [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-php-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Add response type : Text

this.http.PUT('URL',{PARAMS}, {responseType: 'text'})
.subscribe(data => this.data = data)